# Call a function from procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, stored-functions

I can't call my function from a procedure and I don't understand why.
The function is working but in a procedure it does not.

I try to make some code that check if the username already exists in a table that I created.

```
--Boolean Function If Username Exists Or Not

CREATE FUNCTION Fun_Exists_Username
    (@Username_to_check VARCHAR(10))
RETURNS INT 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Boolean BIT

    IF EXISTS (SELECT UserName FROM UTBL_Players WHERE @Username_to_check = UserName)
        SET @Boolean = 1
     ELSE 
        SET @Boolean = 0

     RETURN @Boolean
END

-- Procedure that get username and chek it
CREATE PROCEDURE Usp_Username
    @UserName VARCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Boolean INT

    SELECT @Boolean = Fun_Exists_Username(@UserName)

    IF @Boolean = 0
        PRINT 'This user name already exists.
            You can use this user name: '   -- function that returns a free username
    ELSE 
        PRINT 'This user name is fine'
END
```

I get this error:

> Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Procedure Usp_Username, Line 7 [Batch Start Line 24]      'Fun_Exists_Username' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Do you get an error message? How do you know it isn't working?

Comment: do you really mean mysql? it doesn't look like it and workbench doesn't like it also

Comment: in SQL Server you must fully qualify functions with the schema name, so if `dbo` is your default scheme then you call it with `select @Boolean = dbo.Fun_Exists_Username(@UserName)`

Answer (score 2):

You **must use** a schema prefix when creating and when calling the function.

So change the creation to:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Fun_Exists_Username
```

and when calling it, use this:

```
SELECT @Boolean = dbo.Fun_Exists_Username(@UserName)
```

Comment: In fact you should [always specify schema prefix](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix) for all object references.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
IF EXISTS (SELECT UserName FROM UTBL_Players WHERE @Username_to_check = UserName)
```

this if statement should be

```sql
IF EXISTS (SELECT UserName FROM UTBL_Players WHERE UserName = @Username_to_check)
```